# Gala high CPU usage in VirtualBox

Tags: gala

I am currently running Elementary OS inside VirtualBox on a MacBook Pro. I freshly installed elementary OS, updated and upgraded everything, installed VirtualBox Guest Additions, and ran `sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-dkms`.

Immediately after the upgrade, Gala began using a large amount of the CPU. This is fixed by killing Gala after logging in. When Gala restarts there seem to be no further problems and everything is fine.

I have plenty of RAM, CPU cores, and Video Memory allotted in VirtualBox settings. I also have 3D acceleration enabled (same issue even when it is disabled). Is this just a bug or do I need to further configure elementary OS for VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and rectified by selecting **VMSVGA** as graphics driver.

[image: Graphics Driver]